# How can I plot Posix data hourly in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I have a dataframe:

```
bvar time
0.000000000 2003-03-14 19:00:00
0.200000000 2003-03-14 20:00:00
0.044000000 2003-03-14 21:00:00
```

Here, time is POSIXct:

```
str(tsdat$time)
 POSIXct[1:193], format: "2003-03-14 19:00:00"
```

When I plot it, I want to control the x-axis by showing every hour:

```
ggplot(ts) +
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=bvar))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%Y %H:%M")) + 
  ylab('BVAR [mm]')
```

#### ERROR

Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

How can I make this hourly? In another question, they suggested using `as.Date`. But this doesn't work for me as my data is for 2 days only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `scale_x_datetime` for POSIXct instead of `scale_x_date`. To get hourly breaks on the xaxis, also add `breaks = "1 hour"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(ts) +
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=bvar))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))+
  scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%Y %H:%M"), breaks = "1 hour") + 
  ylab('BVAR [mm]')
```

**Output**

[image: plot using scale_x_datetime]

**Data**

```
ts <- structure(list(bvar = c(0, 0.2, 0.044), time = structure(c(1047690000, 
1047693600, 1047697200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```